# how to connect the asp.net web application to kannel SMS gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a project assigned in which whatever mail alerts be generated sent as a sms to the user who is using that web application.I want to know that how to use kannel as a SMS gateway to connect to my Web application and what are the steps required?
Can anybody help me on this topic?
I want some Documentation regarding this topic......

Answer (score 1):

From the [Kannel faq](http://www.kannel.org/faq.shtml#1.1):

```
3.4 What SMSC protocols does the SMS part of the gateway support? 

CIMD 1.3, CIMD 2.0, SMPP 3.4, UCP/EMI 4.0, SEMA SMS2000 OIS protocol for 
SMS centers  over Radiopad and X.25 and several modems and mobile phones 
through AT protocol
```

This means Kannel is intended to talk to mobile phones directly.  Unless you work in the networking division of a mobile phone operator, you will not get access to phones at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what platform you are using. You also need a smsc connection with an smsc provider so that kannel can send the sms to the destination msisdn's.
Lets say someone enters some text in your web app to send over to a msisdn. The process goes like this.
The web application stores the sms in a database.Afterwards another application or a service can query that database and send that sms with a specific format to the Kannel sms gateway. Afterwards kannel routes that message to the destination smsc. You can also use other sms gateway systems than kannel. There are  applications that can talk directly to the smsc's provider (kannel can be called  an application anyway) so u dont need to do all that process. You can use for example a windows server and have all those applications and databases there and talk directly to the providers application. Of course everything (protocols , connectivity) depends on the provider.

Of course as Andomar said above **you can talk directly to msisdn's** if you dont plan to use a provider. You can achieve this through gsm modems.